# How to duplicate an array with itself using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm currently doing the following:

```
_.map(_.shuffle(myMapping), (item, index) => (
  <p>{item.title}</p>
))
```

How can I essentially duplicate myMapping so that myMapping = myMapping + myMapping?

I'm not trying to remove duplicate, I was the copy to be 2x in length.

Answer (score 2):

Using lodash

```
var myMapping  = [1,2,3,4,5]
var myMappingPlus = _.flatten(
   _.map(myMapping, function(v) { return [v, v];});
 );
```

You map an element to an array and then flatten it.

Comment: You can shuffle the whole thing `_.shuffle(myMappingPlus)` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method concatenates arrays:

```
_.map(_.shuffle(myMapping.concat(myMapping)), (item, index) => (
  <p>{item.title}</p>
))
```